# pandas create new column based on boolean value

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe like this with Boolean values

| black | yellow | orange |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |

I want a separate column that summarizes the Boolean values based on column name
which the column would be

| summary |
| --- |
| black, yellow, orange |
| yellow |
| black, yellow |
| orange |

Any idea how to do this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use each row as a selection mask to filter the column names:

```py
(
    df.astype("bool")
    .apply(lambda row: ", ".join(df.columns[row]), axis=1)
    .to_frame("summary")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using pd.DataFrame.dot:

```
df_colors['summary'] = df_colors.dot(df_colors.columns+', ').str.strip(', ')
df_colors
```

Output:

```
   black  yellow  orange                summary
0   True    True    True  black, yellow, orange
1  False    True   False                 yellow
2   True    True   False          black, yellow
3  False   False    True                 orange
```